# Reading history of Safari on Jailbroken iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, jailbreak

I am developing an app for a Jailbroken iPhone device that reads Safari web history. I know that history is stored at `/private/var/mobile/Library/Safari/History.plist`, so I wrote the following code to access it. I have a jailbroken iPhone 3GS with me.

```
NSString *plistPath  = @"/private/var/mobile/Library/Safari/History.plist";
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
            NSLog(@"History does not exist %@",plistPath);

        }else{
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
        }
```

When I debug this code on my iPhone 3GS, it can not find the file at this path. I have browsed my device through `iExplorer` software and I can access the `History.plist` file using `iExplorer`. Can anyone please guide me why my code is not able to access the plist file?

Thanks and Best Regards.

Comment: You program using Xcode?

Comment: Yes Neeku I am using Xcode 5

Comment: Hmm... and you can actually build and run projects into an iPhone 3GS? Because, it's not supported anymore and Xcode wouldn't accept it, even if it's jailbroken, as far as I know... :-/

Comment: Yes you are right, I compile and install the app on iOS device using xcode. So how should I proceed then?

Comment: Well, my point of asking was: I'm interested in knowing how you can use that device with Xcode 5, since it is already obsolete. However, I'll suggest messing with `chmod`, permissions of the file, like setting it to `777` and then trying. Also you haven't mentioned what exactly happens when it can't find the file. Any errors? Warnings?

Comment: Neeku, fileExistsAtPath return false when I check the existence of History.plist file. Can you please guide me how can I set permission of file using chmod. Since I have never done this so please help me. I am running iOS 6.1.2 on iPhone 3gs so its working well with xcode 5

Comment: Search and you'll find it. I don't have an iExplorer handy, and I can't remember if you could manipulate files through it. You just need the right tool and there's nothing complicated about that afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of sandbox. Your app doesn't have access to History.plist from it. Try to copy your app to /Applications folder in your iPhone via iExplorer.